# how to paste conditional formatting as relative cell reference or apply it on a selected range

Tags: google-sheets

What I try to do is to give a GREEN color to a cell in a row if the previous cell is less and RED the cell is less than its previous:
Please check this video to illuminate what I want to describe:

https://www.loom.com/share/46470e78ae7b49699ce83d7c268dd459
[Conditional formatting on row range in Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTQby.png)

The problem is that, as seen in the video and the screenshot, the conditional formatting cell references do not change when applied to a row, even if I did not use $. How can I manage to have relative references for each cell to its previous in a row?
For example, when setting GREEN color if the cell C1 is greater than B1 (IF =C1>B1 set the color GREEN), in the next cell D1 the conditional formatting should automatically be referencing: IF =D1>C1 set the color GREEN.

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply to the columns C and D, set your `Apply to range` to `C:D`.

Set 2 conditions with `Custom formula is`:

- for the `green` styling: `=AND(LEN(C:C),B:B<C:C)`
- for the `red` styling: `=AND(LEN(C:C),B:B>C:C)`

If you need to expand over more column, just expand the range.

[image]